# Dynamically get value of specific element from list of elements with same id

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make a star rating feature and I'm stuck on setting the value dynamically from a variable. I don't want to make it so that the stars are interactive. I want them to be set or filled using the variable's value.

This is how I'm getting the stars

```html
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span class="rating" data-rating="0">
        <i class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="1">&#9733;</i>
        <i class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="2">&#9733;</i>
        <i class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="3">&#9733;</i>
        <i class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="4">&#9733;</i>
        <i class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="5">&#9733;</i>
    </span>
    <span>
        <input class="coach-id" hidden value="{{ coach.id }}">
    </span>
</div>
```

Now, my issue is that I'm generating this block of code `n` amount of times for as many entries as I have in my database. This creates an issue that every block will have the same class.

I want to be able to set them dynamically through a variable specific to each block. Meaning every entry in the DB will have a rating column which will be the value of the stars corresponding to that entry.

Right now, the stars are interactive through the following script

```js
const ratings = document.querySelectorAll('.rating');
const coach_id = document.querySelector('.coach-id').value;
ratings.forEach(rating =>
    rating.addEventListener('mouseleave', ratingHandler)
);
const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.rating .star');
stars.forEach(star => {
    star.addEventListener('mouseover', starSelection);
    star.addEventListener('mouseleave', starSelection);
    star.addEventListener('click', activeSelect);
});
function ratingHandler(e) {
    const childStars = e.target.children;
    for(let i = 0; i < childStars.length; i++) {
        const star = childStars.item(i)
        if (star.dataset.checked === "true") {
            star.classList.add('hover');
        }
        else {
            star.classList.remove('hover');
        }
    }
}

function starSelection(e) {
    const parent = e.target.parentElement
    const childStars = parent.children;
    const dataset = e.target.dataset;
    const note = +dataset.note; // Convert note (string) to note (number)
    for (let i = 0; i < childStars.length; i++) {
        const star = childStars.item(i)
        if (+star.dataset.note > note) {
            star.classList.remove('hover');
        } else {
            star.classList.add('hover');
        }
    }
}
function activeSelect(e) {
    const parent = e.target.parentElement
    const childStars = parent.children;
    const dataset = e.target.dataset;
    const note = +dataset.note; // Convert note (string) to note (number)
    for (let i = 0; i < childStars.length; i++) {
        const star = childStars.item(i)
        if (+star.dataset.note > note) {
            star.classList.remove('hover');
            star.dataset.checked = "false";
        } else {
            star.classList.add('hover');
            star.dataset.checked = "true";
        }
    }
    const noteTextElement = parent.parentElement.lastElementChild.children.item(0)
    noteTextElement.innerText = `Note: ${note}`;
    console.log(note);
    let url = `/coach/editRating/${coach_id}/${note}`
    window.location.href = url
    console.log(url)
}
```

Comment: *"I want to be able to set them dynamically through a variable specific to each block."* What do you mean by "set them"?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I aplogoize I meant class not id I'll correct myself. As for the second question, each block of html stars is being created from within a for loop (TWIG I'm working with Symfony). Now each iteration of the loop is basically displaying an entry in the Table Coach in my DB. So each block of stars generated in each iteration is specifically related to that entry or row being displayed with that iteration. Now in this table I have a rating column with values unique to each row or entry. I'm getting these values and I want to set the corresponding stars with them.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Don'tPanic The issue is that I don't know how to set the stars each with the value corresponding to it independently of other stars. You could think of each set of stars  as a Person. That person then has a rating stored in the DB. I can get that variable for all Persons and hand it to the template with that person's ID in an associative array no problem there. But I don't know how to then associate for example the first pair of person id and rating with a set of stars. The second problem is that I couldn't really figure out how to set the stars visually I mean.

Comment: AFAICT all the JS you have shown is related to interactivity - mouse in/out and clicks?  But your question is nothing about that, and in fact says "*I don't want to make it so that the stars are interactive*" ...?  I'd suggest editing your question and focussing just on one problem you're having.  Try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Lastly, 5-star rating systems in Javascript are extremely common, and there are hundreds of related questions and answers here on SO. If you're not sure where to start, they might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Moudhaffer Bouallegui - Please find the sample star rating page.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("i.fa-star").forEach(function(element,position){
            element.addEventListener("click",function(){
                this.style.color = "yellow";
              //  this.style.fontSize = "35px";
                let noOfStar = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("input[name=star]").value;

                document.querySelectorAll("i.fa-star").forEach(function(e,p){
                    e.style.color = "rgb(126, 126, 126)";
                    
                    if((p+1) <= noOfStar){
                        e.style.color = "yellow";
                    }
                })

            })

           
        })
```

```css
    input[type=radio]{
        display: none;
    }
    .card{
        max-width: 350px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 #000;
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        cursor : pointer;
    }
    .fa-star{
        font-size: 30px;
        color: rgb(126, 126, 126);
        transition: 0.1s ease-in-out all;
    }
    .stars{
        padding:10px;
        height: 40px;
        
    }
    button{
        width: 70%;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        background-color: rgb(107, 107, 107);
        padding:10px;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    button:hover{
        box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 yellow;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    .fa-star{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="card">
        <h2>Give your stars</h2>
        <div class="stars">
            <span><label><i for="star1" class="fa fa-star"></i></label><input type="radio" name="star" id="star1"
                    value="1"></span>
            <span><label><i for="star2" class="fa fa-star"></i></label><input type="radio" name="star" id="star2"
                    value="2"></span>
            <span><label><i for="star3" class="fa fa-star"></i></label><input type="radio" name="star" id="star3"
                    value="3"></span>
            <span><label><i for="star4" class="fa fa-star"></i></label><input type="radio" name="star" id="star4"
                    value="4"></span>
            <span><label><i for="star5" class="fa fa-star"></i></label><input type="radio" name="star" id="star5"
                    value="5"></span>
        </div>
       
    </div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer very much but this lets me create interactive stars that I can click to set. What I want to do is set the stars when the page loads up with values from DB.  I have the values but I can't figure out how to set the stars on page load

Comment: Hi @MoudhafferBouallegui, Please refer the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9bo1n2mu/), just call the javascript function in onload and pass your database value to the function.